# after add new row, the dropdownlist return default

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have a `GridView` control with an `<asp:TemplateField>` including both a DropDownList control (`ddlItem`) in the main part and a button in the footer (`ButtonAdd`). When I click the button, the drop down list resets to the default values and the selection returns to where it was.

Previously I was able to click the button and drop down list items and selection would remain. It broke when I set `AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlItem_SelectedIndexChanged"`. I did this soI can show or refresh the `NoTagging` section according to the selected `KodItem`.

How can I continue to refresh the `NoTagging` section but not lose my drop down list state?

Here is my code:

```
<asp:gridview ID="Gridview1" CssClass="table table-bordered table-condensed"  runat="server"  ShowFooter="True"  
                             AutoGenerateColumns="False"  
                             OnRowCreated="Gridview1_RowCreated" CellPadding="4" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#336666" BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="3px" GridLines="Horizontal" >  
    <Columns>  
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Bil" />  
        <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Nama Peralatan">  
            <ItemTemplate>  
                
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlItem" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlItem_SelectedIndexChanged" AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataSourceID="sqlItem" DataTextField="NamaItem" DataValueField="KodItem" class="form-control">  
                </asp:DropDownList>

                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlItem" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Integration2019ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [NamaItem], [KodItem] FROM [Sistict_tblMaklumatPeralatan] WHERE ([Unit] = @Kategori)">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="" Name="Kategori" QueryStringField="Kategori" Type="String" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </ItemTemplate> 
             <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />  
            <FooterTemplate>  
                 <strong><asp:Label ID="Remark" runat="server" Text="Klik butang TAMBAH jika ada pertambahan peralatan"></asp:Label></strong>
                <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server"   
                                     Text="Tambah"   
                                     onclick="ButtonAdd_Click" CausesValidation="false" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </FooterTemplate>   
        </asp:TemplateField>  
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="No Tagging">  
            <ItemTemplate>  
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNoTagging" runat="server"  
                                          AppendDataBoundItems="True" class="form-control" DataSourceID="sqlListTagging" DataTextField="NoTagging" DataValueField="IDItem">  
                    
                  
                </asp:DropDownList>  
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlListTagging" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Integration2019ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [IDItem], [NoTagging], [NamaItem], [KodItem] FROM [Sistict_tblMaklumatPeralatan] WHERE ([StatusItemSemasa] = @StatusItemSemasa) AND ([Kategori] = @Kategori) AND ([KodItem] = @KodItem)">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="0" Name="StatusItemSemasa" Type="String" />
                         <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="" Name="Kategori" QueryStringField="Kategori" Type="String" />
                         <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlItem" Name="KodItem" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                       
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </ItemTemplate>  
        </asp:TemplateField>  
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">  
            <ItemTemplate>  
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"   
                                        onclick="LinkButton1_Click" CausesValidation="false" class="btn btn-danger" >Hapus</asp:LinkButton> 
            </ItemTemplate>  
        </asp:TemplateField>  
    </Columns>  

          <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
          <HeaderStyle BackColor="#336666" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
          <PagerStyle BackColor="#336666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
          <RowStyle ForeColor="#333333" BackColor="White" />
          <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#339966" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
          <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
          <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#487575" />
          <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E5E5E5" />
          <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#275353" />
</asp:gridview>
```

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Dim username, kodstaf As String
        username = Request.QueryString("usr")
        kodstaf = Request.QueryString("Staf")
        lblName.Text = GetNamaStaf(username)
        Dim idkodpinjaman As String
        idkodpinjaman = Request.QueryString("KodPinjaman")

        Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbconnection").ConnectionString
        Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(constr)
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * from Sistict_tblMaklumatPinjaman WHERE KodPinjaman= '" & idkodpinjaman & "' AND (StatusSokong IS NOT NULL AND StatusLulus IS NULL) ORDER BY TarikhMohon DESC")
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.Connection = conn
        conn.Open()

        Dim sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        sdr.Read()
        If sdr.HasRows Then

            
            SetInitialRow()

        End If
    End If
End Sub

'clear the existing notagging after choose new KodItem in ddlItem 
Protected Sub ddlItem_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim ddlItem As DropDownList = CType(sender, DropDownList)
    Dim row As GridViewRow = CType(ddlItem.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
    Dim ddlNoTagging As DropDownList = CType(row.FindControl("ddlNoTagging"), DropDownList)

    ' Clear existing items
    ddlNoTagging.Items.Clear()

    ' Rebind ddlNoTagging based on the new selected KodItem
    Dim sqlListTagging As SqlDataSource = CType(row.FindControl("sqlListTagging"), SqlDataSource)
    sqlListTagging.SelectParameters("KodItem").DefaultValue = ddlItem.SelectedValue
    ddlNoTagging.DataSourceID = "sqlListTagging"
    ddlNoTagging.DataBind()
End Sub

Protected Sub OnRowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("lblRowNumber"), Label).Text = (e.Row.RowIndex + 1).ToString()
    End If
End Sub
Protected Sub ButtonAdd_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    AddNewRowToGrid()
End Sub

Private Sub AddNewRowToGrid()
    If ViewState("CurrentTable") IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim dtCurrentTable As DataTable = CType(ViewState("CurrentTable"), DataTable)
        Dim drCurrentRow As DataRow = Nothing

        If dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow()
            drCurrentRow("RowNumber") = dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count + 1
            dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow)
            ViewState("CurrentTable") = dtCurrentTable

            Gridview1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable
            Gridview1.DataBind()
        End If
    Else
        Response.Write("ViewState is null")
    End If

    SetPreviousData()
End Sub

Private Sub SetPreviousData()
    Dim rowIndex As Integer = 0

    If ViewState("CurrentTable") IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim dt As DataTable = CType(ViewState("CurrentTable"), DataTable)

        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then

            For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                Dim ddl1 As DropDownList = CType(Gridview1.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(1).FindControl("ddlItem"), DropDownList)
                Dim ddl2 As DropDownList = CType(Gridview1.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(2).FindControl("ddlNoTagging"), DropDownList)

                ' Fill dropdown lists only if they are not null
                If ddl1 IsNot Nothing AndAlso ddl2 IsNot Nothing Then
                    FillDropDownList(ddl1)
                    FillDropDownList(ddl2)

                    If i < dt.Rows.Count - 1 Then
                        ' Check if ddl2.Items is not null and has items
                        If ddl2.Items IsNot Nothing AndAlso ddl2.Items.Count > 0 Then
                            ddl2.ClearSelection()
                            Dim itemToSelect As ListItem = ddl2.Items.FindByText(dt.Rows(i)("Column2").ToString())
                            If itemToSelect IsNot Nothing Then
                                itemToSelect.Selected = True
                            Else
                                ' Handle the case where the item is not found in the DropDownList
                                ' You may want to log a message or take other appropriate action.
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Else
                    ' Handle the case where ddl1 or ddl2 is not found
                    ' You may want to log a message or take other appropriate action.
                End If

                rowIndex += 1
            Next
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SetInitialRow()
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("RowNumber", GetType(String)))
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column1", GetType(String)))
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column2", GetType(String)))

    Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
    dr("RowNumber") = 1
    dt.Rows.Add(dr)

    ViewState("CurrentTable") = dt
    Gridview1.DataSource = dt
    Gridview1.DataBind()

    Dim ddl1 As DropDownList = CType(Gridview1.Rows(0).Cells(1).FindControl("ddlItem"), DropDownList)
    Dim ddl2 As DropDownList = CType(Gridview1.Rows(0).Cells(2).FindControl("ddlNoTagging"), DropDownList)

    FillDropDownList(ddl1)
    FillDropDownList(ddl2)
End Sub
Private Sub FillDropDownList(ByVal ddl As DropDownList)
    '    Dim arr As ArrayList = GetDummyData()

    '    For Each item As ListItem In arr
    '         ddl.Items.Add(item)
    '    Next
End Sub
Protected Sub LinkButton1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim lb As LinkButton = CType(sender, LinkButton)
    Dim gvRow As GridViewRow = CType(lb.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
    Dim rowID As Integer = gvRow.RowIndex

    If ViewState("CurrentTable") IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim dt As DataTable = CType(ViewState("CurrentTable"), DataTable)

        If dt.Rows.Count > 1 Then

            If gvRow.RowIndex < dt.Rows.Count - 1 Then
                dt.Rows.Remove(dt.Rows(rowID))
                ResetRowID(dt)
            End If
        End If

        ViewState("CurrentTable") = dt
        Gridview1.DataSource = dt
        Gridview1.DataBind()
    End If

    SetPreviousData()
End Sub
Protected Sub Gridview1_RowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim dt As DataTable = CType(ViewState("CurrentTable"), DataTable)
        Dim lb As LinkButton = CType(e.Row.FindControl("LinkButton1"), LinkButton)

        If lb IsNot Nothing Then

            If dt.Rows.Count > 1 Then

                If e.Row.RowIndex = dt.Rows.Count - 1 Then
                    lb.Visible = False
                End If
            Else
                lb.Visible = False
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub ResetRowID(ByVal dt As DataTable)
    Dim rowNumber As Integer = 1

    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then

        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
            row(0) = rowNumber
            rowNumber += 1
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Too much code to wade through, but the short answer is to do this in javascript, from the browser, instead of via postback to VB. As a bonus, this will also make the page more responsive to your user and reduce load on your server.

Comment: Yikes, came back because I was looking for a previous comment from about this time, and when I look again I also see this is crazy-vulnerable to SQL injection. It would be **trivial** to run any arbitrary SQL I wanted against your database just by putting the SQL in the `KodPinjaman` query parameter and preceding it with `';`. For example, I could _easily_ tell this to `DROP TABLE Sistict_tblMaklumatPinjaman; -- `  **Parameterized queries**: learn them, _use them_.